# Does hereditary 2-coloring imply polychromatic 3-coloring for large edges?

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry, graph-colorings, hypergraph

For a hypergraph $\mathcal H=(V,\mathcal E)$, denote by $m_k$ the smallest number for which we can $k$-color any $X\subset V$ such that for any $E\in \mathcal E$ with $|E\cap X|\ge m_k$ all $k$ colors occur in $E\cap X$. Berge proved that $m_2=2$ if and only if every odd cycle has an edge containing three vertices of the cycle, and that this also implies $m_k=k$ for every $k$.

> Does $m_2=3$ imply any upper bound on $m_3$?

The best constructions I know give $m_3=5$.
*Update.* There is a [better construction](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.04603).
Similar questions have been extensively studied for geometric hypergraphs, see http://coge.elte.hu/cogezoo.html.

**Permanent bounty!** I'm happy to award a 500 bounty for a solution anytime!

Comment: It is worth mentioning that "odd cycle" refers to a set of odd many *edges* such that $e_i\cap e_{i+1}$ is non-empty.  In particular, if $\mathcal{H}=\{12,13,23,123\}$, then $12,13,23$ is an odd cycle, but the edge 123 is not a part of the cycle.

Comment: BTW, another related question is if a hypergraph has a hereditary $c$-coloring, whether it also has a $k$-coloring such that every large enough hyperedge has at least $\lfloor 2k/c\rfloor$ colors?